# Noetherian induction application

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

I have a question about typical application of
Noetherian induction in proofs as [this](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0BD9) one or [this](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/03RY).

The common strategy in both examples as summarizable as that we have a (locally) Noetherian scheme $X$ and aim to
show that $X$ has property $\mathcal{P}$. In the proofs instead
one shows that there exist for every generic point $\eta_i$ of $X$
an afine open neighbourhood $W_i \subset X$ for which
$\mathcal{P}$ holds and then one claims that applying Noetherian
induction this suffice to show that $\mathcal{P}$
holds already for $X$.

Why this is a consequence of Noetherian induction? Noetherian
induction says something like to show that property
$\mathcal{P}$ holds for a scheme $X$ it suffice to show that
for every closed $Y \subsetneq X$ if $\mathcal{P}$ holds
for every closed $Y' \subsetneq Y$ then $\mathcal{P}$ holds
for $Y$.

Why to apply Noetherian induction in this vein above
it is sufficient in proofs above to
show that there exist open neighbuorhoods of generic points
for which $\mathcal{P}$ holds?

Comment: I think in both your examples, this is simply the statement that an ascending sequence of open subsets of a noetherian scheme must stabilise.

Comment: @DamianRössler: yes thanks, seems of course heuristically plausible to call such argumentation also "Noetherian induction". However, this is of course a rather misleading usage of terminology, because there seems on the other hand to exist a fairly precise [definition](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/47837/noetherian-induction) of what a Noetherian induction should be supposed to be.

Comment: Yes but noetherian induction can be used for ordered (noetherian…) sets more generally (see https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Noetherian_induction ) so it would be a special case of noetherian induction for an ordered set.